# How to create a store map using LeafLet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, cartography

Im looking to create a map that can be interactive.

The best option that I found is leaflet, the thing is I don't find any resource explaining how to create my own map.

Im looking to create a mall map where user can see all the stores, fountain ...

How could I achieve that ?

Comment: Did you already take a look at the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API)?

Comment: This is very interesting question! I had developed an Android app on 2012 where I used Ericsson's indoor [Map API](http://indoorlbs.blogspot.gr/2011/10/ericsson-indoor-maps-and-positioning.html), which it was exactly what I needed (creation of map in xml format, drawing venues, position, etc) but it shut down. Since then I made a lot of searching and found [Google Floor Plan](http://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/) which I haven't made any success using it (I didn't try it much) and also found bing maps (which has already defined indoor maps for big malls around the globe).

Comment: Also you can take a look at [indoorAtlas](https://developer.indooratlas.com/dashboard). It's not free but it has free plan with some limitations. Finally, there are also some [open source](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Indoor_Mapping) solutions but haven't tried yet.

Comment: As we are in 2017, after two years, what would you recommend me for custom indoor navigation?

Answer (score 2):

The best place to start would be the Leaflet examples page:

http://leafletjs.com/examples.html

Here is the quick start guide: http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html

**Update**
To create an indoor map, you can use tools such as QGis and Mapbox Studio  to build the map and generate the map tiles(used for web). Then you can use your custom map tiles as a tile layer in leaflet to provide zoom in/out functionality and markers.

Comment: I don't think that leaflet lets you create your own custom indoor map. Actually in the docs says `creation` but you should provide the layers and the layers is what you need when you ask about how to create a custom indoor map.