# how to implement a arbitrary map using leaflet?

Tags: javascript, android, leaflet

I want to implement an android map for indoor positioning, which has a map of a building with some floors and one can see his position in the building. My question is about the implementing the map.

till now, I have found this way: I want to use leaflet, which is a library for manipulation of maps using JS. after that, I want to connect it to the android app using webview.

I searched about leaflet, looked its tutorials and somehow its docs. I found [this](https://github.com/cbaines/leaflet-indoor) plugin named leaflet-Indoor. but since I want my app to be offline, I got stuck in creating the map of building. for now, I dont want a complicated one... just something simple. on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701804/how-to-create-a-store-map-using-leaflet) page, it is suggested to use Mapbox studio or QGIS. since Mapbox studio is not free, I installed QGIS. but it seems a little difficult to work with.

now my question is...

is the way I have chosen a good one or you suggest another one??

and what is the best way to create a map of a building for using with leaflet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar situation and choosed to use Leaflet with overlay image maps.
Generating PNG images from AutoCAD or PDF is simple (4000x4000 bits images; around 500Kb / floor).
You must use L.CRS.Simple in Leaflet as your coordinate reference system and use imageoverlay ([http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html](http://Sample))

Plugins for Leaflet were very useful (Draw,..).